# Parsing a file line-by-line and computing a minimum over a function of the lines in a Pythonic way

Tags: python

I have a file composed of blocks of lines, separated by special lines indicating that the block ended.

Say, a file looks like this:

```
1
5
BLOCK END
13
BLOCK END
3
4
5
BLOCK END
```

For each line I compute a value `loss(x)`, and I want to save the best value for each block, i.e. in the end I want a list that gives for each block the minimum of the function`loss` over all value of the block.

So the output is equal to 
`[min(f(1),f(5)),f(13),...]`

The following code does that:

```
best_value = np.inf
with open(path) as f:
    for line in f:
        if line_means_block_ended():
            block_values.append(best_block_value)
            best_value = np.inf
        else:
            best_block_value = min(candidate(line), best_value , key = loss)
print block_values
```

I feel this code is not optimal, because of the initialization to `np.inf` and the hard-coded `min` computation. Is there a more Pythonic way?

Comment: if you can post a sample of your file and the desired output for that sample, we could understand better your intentions and help you more

Comment: Okay, I added an example.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest pyparsing for this task.

```
import pyparsing as pp
```

Create the dictionary for parsing the text

```
# More than one number can appear before block end
number_pattern = pp.OneOrMore(pp.Word(pp.nums))

# Suppressing, so that it doesn't appear in the matches
block_end_pattern = pp.Suppress(pp.Word("BLOCK END"))

# Group the pattern, so that all match appear as a list
pattern = pp.OneOrMore(pp.Group(number_pattern + block_end_pattern))
```

Match the sample text

```
text = """
1
5
BLOCK END
13
BLOCK END
3
4
5
BLOCK END
"""    

matches = pattern.parseString(text)
```

Prepare the output

```
output = []

for val in matches:
    if len(val) > 1:
        # Convert array to the form "f(v)"
        val = ['f(' + v + ')' for v in val]

        # Join the array elements using "," and add "min()"
        output.append("min(" + ",".join(val) + ")")
    else:
        output.append( 'f(' + val[0] + ')')

# Join the final output by ","
block_values = ",".join(output)
```

Output (block_values):

```
min(f(1),f(5)),f(13),min(f(3),f(4),f(5))
```